# Automated horizontal scrolling in jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin which does scrolling the element (div) when I hover the arrow, it should look like this: http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/5716/scrollp.jpg and scroll automatically the content inside to the left/right only when user hovers arrows.

Is there anything like this?

Thanks a lot, Jakub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://flesler.blogspot.com/2008/02/jqueryserialscroll.html

I have used it in several places, but i havent tried it like i think you want it to, but since you can do stuff like :

```
$(container).trigger( 'start' );
$(container).trigger( 'stop' );
```

you should be able to do those start and stop on mouseover events.

Alan.

Answer (score 1):

any "do it yourself" solution should contain

```
$("#divid").animate({
   'scrollLeft':  '400px'
}, 3000);
```

for instance